# Blazor wasm very slow rendering of large list of content

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a performance issue with my blazor wasm application. First understand that there are some design constraints that i cannot change. These include:

1. The website must be "infine" scroll.
2. The website has to be able to jump to content on the page, which means that i probably need to have everything rendered for this to work.

My list of content can sometimes get very large. In my specific example I have a content list of over 4000 elements, and I can't get it to render at all.

Here is my component

```
@using HolWasm.Client.Helpers.Events
@using HolWasm.Client.Services
@using HolWasmDomain.Entities.KoebSalg
@using HolWasmDomain.Entities.Traad
@using HolWasmDomain.Enums
@using HolWasm.Shared.ViewModels.Traade
@using HolWasm.Client.Helpers
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions
@using System.Diagnostics
@inject DialogState DialogState
@inject TooltipService TooltipService
@inject DialogService DialogService
@inject AdminIpSearchEvent AdminIpSearchEvent
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject SvarService SvarService
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
@inject CurrentUserService CurrentUserService

@if (_loaded && _listSvarViewModel?.Svar != null)
{
    foreach (var post in _listSvarViewModel.Svar)
    {
        <div class="margin-bottom-10px svar-super-container rounded-corners" id="@($"sid{post.Id}")">
            <div class="rz-card card svar-container-box">
                <div class="rz-card-content">
                    <div class="row no-margin-left-right svar-container">
                        <div class="col-3 no-padding-left-right vertical-line-svar">
                            <div class="svar-info-container">
                                <div class="svar-username d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
                                    <span class="background-text">@post.Bruger</span>
                                    <p class="float-right svar-postcount-styling">
                                        #@post.svarCount
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="svar-rank">
                                    @post.Rank
                                </div>
                                <div class="svar-dato">
                                    <span>@post.Dato.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <div class="svar-text">
                                @((MarkupString)post.Indhold)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rz-card-footer">
                    <div class="rz-card-footer-content">
                        <div class="row no-margin-left-right">
                            <div class="col-3 font-size-10 no-padding-left">
                                <a href="" class="svar-item-rapporter-link" @onclick:preventDefault>Rapportér Post</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <div class="signatur">
                                    @((MarkupString)post.Signatur)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        if (post is not null && (!post.IsHidden || IsAdmin || (Traad.Bruger == _userName && post is { IsHidden: true, UserVisible: true })))
        {
            <div class="margin-bottom-10px svar-super-container rounded-corners" id="@($"sid{post.Id}")">
                <div class="rz-card card @(IsAdmin && post is { IsHidden: true, UserVisible: false } ? "admin-hidden-view" : !IsAdmin && post is { IsHidden: true, UserVisible: true } || IsAdmin && post is { IsHidden: true, UserVisible: true } ? "svar-user-hidden" : "svar-container-box") ">
                    @if (IsAdmin)
                    {
                        <div class="rz-card-header justify-content-end" style="padding: 5px 5px 0 0 !important;">
                            <div class="margin-right-5px">
                                <button class="rz-button rz-button-sm btn-primary" @onclick="@(ShowEditAdminSvarDialogButtons[post.Id].Action)">Ret</button>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="margin-right-5px">
                                @if (post.Visible)
                                {
                                    <button class="rz-button rz-button-sm btn-primary" @onclick="@(ShowHideDialogButtons[post.Id].Action)">Skjul</button>
                                }
                                @if (!post.Visible)
                                {
                                    <button class="rz-button rz-button-sm btn-primary" @onclick="@(ShowSvarDialogButtons[post.Id].Action)">Vis</button>
                                }
                            </div>
                            <div class="margin-right-5px">
                                <button class="rz-button rz-button-sm btn-primary" @onclick="@(SeeActivityFromIpButtons[post.Id].Action)">@post.Ip</button>
                            </div>
                            @if (post.modsvar > 0)
                            {
                                <div class="margin-right-5px">
                                    <button class="rz-button rz-button-sm btn-primary" @onclick="@(ShowChangesInSvarDialogButtons[post.Id].Action)">@("Vis ændringer " + post.modsvar)</button>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    }
                    @if (TraadType == TraadType.KoebSalg && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_userName) && _userName == Traad?.Bruger)
                    {
                        <div class="rz-card-header justify-content-end" style="padding: 5px 5px 0 0 !important;">
                            <div class="margin-right-5px">
                                <button class="rz-button rz-button-sm btn-primary" @onclick="@(ShowHideKoebSalgDialogButtons[post.Id].Action)">Skjul</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                    @if (post.IsEditable && !post.IsGuest)
                    {
                        <div class="rz-card-header justify-content-end" style="padding: 5px 5px 0 0 !important;">
                            <div class="margin-right-5px">
                                <button class="rz-button rz-button-sm btn-primary" @onclick="@(EditSvarDialogButtons[post.Id].Action)">Ret</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                    <div class="rz-card-content">
                        <div class="row no-margin-left-right svar-container">
                            <div class="col-3 no-padding-left-right vertical-line-svar">
                                <div class="svar-info-container">
                                    <div class="svar-username d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
                                        @if (post.IsGuest)
                                        {
                                            if (IsAdmin)
                                            {
                                                <span @ref="@_guest" @onmouseover="@(ShowToolTipActions[post.Id])" class="background-text">@post.Bruger</span>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <span class="background-text">@post.Bruger</span>
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <a href="@($"/profil/{post.ProfilId}")">@post.Bruger</a>
                                        }
                                        <p class="float-right svar-postcount-styling">
                                            #@post.svarCount
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="svar-rank">
                                        @post.Rank
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="svar-dato">
                                        <span>@post.Dato.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")</span>
                                    </div>
                                    @if (Traad is KsTraad && post.Validering.ToUpper() == "NEMID")
                                    {
                                        <span> | </span>
                                        <img src="@($"_content/SharedStyling/images/NEMID_{Theme}.svg")" alt="NemId Valideret" style="max-width: 50px" class=""/>
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <div class="svar-text">
                                    @((MarkupString)post.Indhold)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rz-card-footer">
                        <div class="rz-card-footer-content">
                            <div class="row no-margin-left-right">
                                <div class="col-3 font-size-10 no-padding-left">
                                    <a href="" class="svar-item-rapporter-link" @onclick="RtaButtons[post.Id].Action" @onclick:preventDefault>Rapportér Post</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-9">
                                    <div class="signatur">
                                        @((MarkupString)post.Signatur)
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center padding-bottom-5px padding-top-5px">
        <ReklameComponent Id="div-gpt-ad-rectangle_1"
                          Dimensions="@(new Tuple<int, int>(300, 250))">
        </ReklameComponent>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <LoadingScreen/>
}

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Traad? Traad { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? Theme { get; set; } = "Dark";

    [Parameter]
    public TraadType TraadType { get; set; }

    ElementReference _guest;

    bool _loaded;

    private Dictionary<int, Button> RtaButtons { get; set; } = new();
    private Dictionary<int, Button> ShowEditAdminSvarDialogButtons { get; set; } = new();
    private Dictionary<int, Button> EditSvarDialogButtons { get; set; } = new();
    private Dictionary<int, Button> EditAdminSvarButtons { get; set; } = new();
    private Dictionary<int, Button> ShowHideDialogButtons { get; set; } = new();
    private Dictionary<int, Button> ShowSvarDialogButtons { get; set; } = new();
    private Dictionary<int, Button> SeeActivityFromIpButtons { get; set; } = new();
    private Dictionary<int, Button> ShowChangesInSvarDialogButtons { get; set; } = new();
    private Dictionary<int, Action> ShowToolTipActions { get; set; } = new();
    private Dictionary<int, Button> ShowHideKoebSalgDialogButtons { get; set; } = new();

    ListSvarViewModel? _listSvarViewModel;
    private string? _userName;
    bool _scrolled = false;
    bool _isAuthenticated;

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new();
        timer.Start();
        if (Traad != null) _listSvarViewModel = await SvarService.GetListSvarViewModel(Traad.Id);
        if (_listSvarViewModel?.Svar != null)
        {
            var currentUser = await CurrentUserService.GetCurrentUser();
            if (currentUser is not null)
            {
                _userName = currentUser.Brugernavn;
            }
            _isAuthenticated = await CurrentUserService.IsAuthenticated();
            foreach (var post in _listSvarViewModel.Svar)
            {
                if (post is null) continue;
                var button = new Button
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Action = async (e) => await ShowRta(post.TraadId, post.Id)
                };
                RtaButtons.TryAdd(post.Id, button);
                var editSvarDialogButton = new Button
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Action = async (e) => await EditSvarDialog(post.Id)
                };
                EditSvarDialogButtons.TryAdd(post.Id, editSvarDialogButton);
                var showHideKoebSalgDialogButton = new Button
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Action = async (e) => await ShowHideKoebSalgDialog(post.Id, post.TraadId)
                };
                ShowHideKoebSalgDialogButtons.TryAdd(post.Id, showHideKoebSalgDialogButton);
                if (IsAdmin)
                {
                    var editAdminSvarButton = new Button
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                        Action = async (e) => await ShowEditAdminSvarDialog(post.Id)
                    };
                    ShowEditAdminSvarDialogButtons.TryAdd(post.Id, editAdminSvarButton);
                    var showHideDialogButton = new Button
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                        Action = async (e) => await ShowHideDialog(post.TraadId, post.Id)
                    };
                    ShowHideDialogButtons.TryAdd(post.Id, showHideDialogButton);
                    var showSvarDialogButton = new Button
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                        Action = async (e) => await ShowSvarDialog(post.TraadId, post.Id)
                    };
                    ShowSvarDialogButtons.TryAdd(post.Id, showSvarDialogButton);
                    var seeActivityFromIpButton = new Button
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                        Action = (e) => SeeActivityFromIp(post.Ip)
                    };
                    SeeActivityFromIpButtons.TryAdd(post.Id, seeActivityFromIpButton);
                    var showChangesInSvarDialogButton = new Button
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                        Action = async (e) => await ShowChangesInSvarDialog(post.Id)
                    };
                    ShowChangesInSvarDialogButtons.TryAdd(post.Id, showChangesInSvarDialogButton);
                    ShowToolTipActions.TryAdd(post.Id, () => ShowTooltip(_guest, post.Email));
                }
            }
        }
        _loaded = true;
        timer.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts1 = timer.Elapsed;
        string output = "time it took to fetch: " + ts1.ToString("c");
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (!firstRender && !_scrolled)
        {
            var url = NavigationManager.Uri;
            var sidMatch = Regex.Match(url, "#sid");
            string? svarId;
            if (sidMatch.Success)
            {
                svarId = url[(sidMatch.Index + 1)..];
                await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("BlazorScrollToId", svarId);
                _scrolled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _scrolled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task ShowRta(int threadId, int postId)
    {
        await DialogService.OpenAsync<CreateRTA>("Opret RTA", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "TraadId", threadId }, { "SvarId", postId }, { "IsAuthenticated", _isAuthenticated } });
    }

    private void ShowTooltip(ElementReference elementReference, string content)
    {
        TooltipService.Open(elementReference, content, new TooltipOptions { Position = TooltipPosition.Top });
    }

    private void CloseToolTip()
    {
        TooltipService.Close();
    }

    private async Task EditSvarDialog(int postId)
    {
        await DialogService.OpenAsync<EditSvar>("Ret svar", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "SvarId", postId } });
    }

    private async Task ShowHideDialog(int threadId, int postId)
    {
        await DialogService.OpenAsync<HideSvarDialog>("Skjul", new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "TraadId", threadId }, { "SvarId", postId }, { "IsAuthenticated", true }, { "IsThread", false }, { "TraadType", TraadType } });
    }

    private async Task ShowSvarDialog(int threadId, int postId)
    {
        await DialogService.OpenAsync<ShowSvarDialog>("Vis", new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "TraadId", threadId }, { "SvarId", postId }, { "IsAuthenticated", true }, { "IsThread", false } });
    }

    private async Task ShowChangesInSvarDialog(int postId)
    {
        await DialogService.OpenAsync<ChangeInSvarDialog>("Ændringer", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "SvarId", postId } });
    }

    private async Task ShowEditAdminSvarDialog(int postId)
    {
        await DialogService.OpenAsync<EditAdminAnswerDialog>("Ret svar", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "SvarId", postId } });
    }

    private async Task ShowHideKoebSalgDialog(int postId, int threadId)
    {
        await DialogService.OpenAsync<HideSvarUserKoebSalg>("Skjul", new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "SvarId", postId }, { "IsAuthenticated", true }, { "TraadId", threadId } });
    }

    private void SeeActivityFromIp(string? ip)
    {
        AdminIpSearchEvent.SetIp(ip);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("admin/aktivitet");
    }

}
```

I've tried to follow some of the optimization tips on MS own page (hence the dictionaries with buttons. (I hope i didn't misunderstand how it's to be done).

Anyway. Even simplifying the page, without using any buttons like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < _listSvarViewModel.Svar.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="margin-bottom-10px svar-super-container rounded-corners" id="@($"sid{_listSvarViewModel.Svar[i].Id}")">
            <div class="rz-card card svar-container-box">
                <div class="rz-card-content">
                    <div class="row no-margin-left-right svar-container">
                        <div class="col-3 no-padding-left-right vertical-line-svar">
                            <div class="svar-info-container">
                                <div class="svar-username d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
                                    <span class="background-text">@_listSvarViewModel.Svar[i].Bruger</span>
                                    <p class="float-right svar-postcount-styling">
                                        #@_listSvarViewModel.Svar[i].svarCount
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="svar-rank">
                                    @_listSvarViewModel.Svar[i].Rank
                                </div>
                                <div class="svar-dato">
                                    <span>@_listSvarViewModel.Svar[i].Dato.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <div class="svar-text">
                                @((MarkupString)_listSvarViewModel.Svar[i].Indhold)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rz-card-footer">
                    <div class="rz-card-footer-content">
                        <div class="row no-margin-left-right">
                            <div class="col-3 font-size-10 no-padding-left">
                                <a href="" class="svar-item-rapporter-link" @onclick:preventDefault>Rapportér Post</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <div class="signatur">
                                    @((MarkupString)_listSvarViewModel.Svar[i].Signatur)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Does nothing for the performance.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can improve the performance? I'm considering trying to convince them to use pagination.

The other thing I can see is a complete rewrite away from blazor, and using standard razor pages instead. But that will take a very long time. Blazor server is just as slow for this.

Comment: How does this "jump" work? Based on a filter? I normally wire virtualize to an ODATA endpoint to allow for queries and virtualization (takes and skips).

Comment: Currently it works by looking for "#sid" in the url, and then scrolling to that ID in the dom.

Comment: You will never get performance like you expect. Take the query to the server. ODATA is one way.

Comment: https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/presentation-2021-01-NDCLondon/blob/master/demo/CalendarApp/src/CalendarApp/wwwroot/scroller.js is an attempt to allow virtualize to scroll to...

Comment: Virtualize only works with fixed sized content right ? My content have variable height.

Comment: @ChristianA Yes it uses the size to create empty divs on each end of the list to maintain the feel of a contiguous list.

Comment: I've tried to benchmark fetching the data. It's like 500 ms to fetch the 4000 items. The issue is rendering the html. It's insanely slow.

Comment: It's because your rendering 4000 records even though they are not visible. If the 500ms is ok. Try and removed as much binding as possible. Make is easier for Blazor to process the rendering. The `@key` attribute may help here to help the render engine track the changes.

Comment: I guess i could look into the @key attribute. The 500 ms is just to fetch the data from the server. Afterwards it just hangs in my loading component trying to render the very large list.

Comment: Just went from .net 6 to .net 7 today